# Flash Lite access complex data on the webservice .net based?

Tags: .net, web-services, flashlite

I am new to flashlite/actionscript, my problem is.. how can i call a method in the webservice having complex data(return data and paramters), The web service is .net based and it is tuned for a mobile friendly type of webservice(without xsd:import)... And the problem is brought up when the complex data from/parameter of WS is a structure data of c#... and i think AS/Flash needs some remote access in data handling.... I have read that to have flash remoting you have to install flash remoting in the machine, but is it posible in the Cellphone? How can I handle complex data from/to WS using flashlite in cellphones... sorry I am really new... Hope someone can help me...

i got this error message calling from a WS method ...  complexDataStructure myMethod();
"Unable to connect to endpoint: http://localhost:8001/myservice
undefined"

I can load my Webservice and having no problems on some methods having simple data types... I just dont know what to do with the methods having complex types...

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of what the complex data types are like?

I would be tempted to make your objects from the webservice quite simple, even if it means flash has to do a bit of processing to use them appropriately.